# Renew certificate for a specific port

Tags: ssl, https, certificate, certbot, port80

I am running **HTTPS** on port 80. When I run `certbot renew` I get `400 The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port`. Is there a way to renew the certificate in this setup? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you run HTTPS on port 80 in the first place? Thus is a pretty unexpected setup. Port 80 is used for plain HTTP and port 443 for HTTPS.

Comment: If you are using Linux you can foraward calls from 443 to 80.